# Find the range of (x+1)/(2x+1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently encountered with this question in an exam, but wasn't able to solve it.

At first I equated the og eqn to y and created an eqn in y, but that didn't help. 
 any hint?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't help?

Comment: the eqn I got was: y=(x-+1)/(2x+1) and after simplification: y(2x+1)-x-1=0. Now I have no clue about the next step. :)

Comment: @Harshal: one way to proceed with that approach is to ask: for what values of $y$ will you be unable to find a solution to the resulting equation for $x$? you could get a better grip on that question by simplifying your equation to $(2y-1)x+(y-1)=0$, or $(2y-1)x=1-y$. now what could go wrong if you were to try to solve this for $x$?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback symplectomorphic, can you pls elaborate you ans? I had reached till that step (btw) while getting the equation which I posted in the comment above. :D

Comment: @Harshal: if $2y-1\neq0$, you could divide by it and get a solution for $x$. but if $2y-1=0$, what happens?

Comment: Yeah thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x+1}{2x+1}=M\Rightarrow x+1=2Mx+M\Rightarrow (2M-1)x=1-M\Rightarrow x=\frac{1-M}{2M-1}$$

Does this tell you something about $M$

Comment: Strictly speaking, your arrow at the last step is unlicensed, which is the whole point: you're using the "implies" notation informally.

Comment: @symplectomorphic : Do you think so...? I also think so.. :P

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: @HarshalGajjar : You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Would it help to rewrite it as $\frac12+\frac1{4x+2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: you will often find that determining the range becomes easier if you can write the formula in such a way that $x$ occurs **once only**.  Thus
$$\frac{x+1}{2x+1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x+2}{2x+1}
  =\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{2x+1}\Bigr)\ .$$
Now $x$ cannot equal $-\frac{1}{2}$, and working things out step by step

- $2x+1$ takes all real values except $0$;
- $\dfrac{1}{2x+1}$ takes all real values except $0$;
- $1+\dfrac{1}{2x+1}$ takes all real values except $1$;
- $\dfrac{1}{2}\Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{2x+1}\Bigr)$ takes all real values except $\dfrac{1}{2}$.